# Connect to Bing Merchant Center using phpseclib

Tags: php, ftp, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to use phpseclib in my project to upload a product feed to Bing's Merchant Center using SFTP.  I'm using phpseclib in the same project to upload a product feed to Amazon via SFTP, and it's working correctly, but I can't seem to connect successfully to Bing.

The following code is attempting to connect to Bring:

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP(BING_FTP_SERVER);
if (!$sftp->login(BING_FTP_USERNAME, BING_FTP_PASSWORD)) {
            exit('Login Failed');
}
```

When I run this code, there is about a 10 second delay, and then I get an error saying the login failed and:

```
Cannot connect to feeds.adcenter.microsoft.com. Error 110. Connection timed out
```

To test the credentials, I connected manually using Filezilla, and it works correctly.  However, before connecting, Filezilla shows me a warning saying the server's certificate is unknown and I need to manually approve it before I can connect.  When I use Filezilla to connect direclty to Amazon's FTP server, I do NOT receive this warning.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible this warning is causing the issue.  Do I need to somehow tell my Ubunut server to trust the certificate on Bing's FTP server, basically mimicking the manual approval I was required to give in Filezilla?  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It's PHP's fsockopen() that's given the error. My guess: there's not an /SFTP/ server on BING_FTP_SERVER but rather an FTP server. FTP is on port 21, SFTP, port 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bing merchant FAQ, only the FTP or the FTPS is supported. Not the SFTP. The phpseclib supports the SFTP only. The FTPS and SFTP are completely different protocols.

Refer to PHP manual for its FTP functions:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php